# ReactJS: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref

Hello iam newbie in ReactJS, I'm using a library **[react-bootstrap4-form-validation](https://andyhu92.github.io/react-bootstrap4-form-validation/#/)** to validate my form. From the documentation there are the function that use to reset the form validation. From the documentations there are example to reset the form validation using triggering button *onClick*, like [this](https://andyhu92.github.io/react-bootstrap4-form-validation/#/api/validation-form). And for a condition, i need to reset the validation, but not when triggering button *onClick*, but when the props from parent component is change. Because of these needs I also created a function (*useCompare*) that is used to compare the props received from the parent component.

In short, I want to reset my form, when the props received from the parent component changes, and the code is as shown below.

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { ValidationForm, TextInput } from 'react-bootstrap4-form-validation';
import { useCompare } from '../../services/compare-props';

function TestForm({ form }) {
  const formRefs = useRef();
  

    const handleSubmit = (e, formData, inputs) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(formData)
    }

    if ( !useCompare(form) ) {
        resetForm()
    }


  function resetForm() {
    let formRef = formRefs.current;
    formRef != null ? formRef.resetValidationState(true) : null;
  }

    return (
        <div className="row justify-content-center">
            <div className="col-md-6 col-sm-10">
                <div className="shadow-sm p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded border">
                    <h6>{form.labelForm}</h6>
                    <hr />
                    <ValidationForm  onSubmit={handleSubmit} id="form-test" ref={formRefs}>
                        {form.field.map(function (fields, index) {
                            return (
                                <div className="row form-group mb-1" key={index}>
                                    <div className="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">{fields.label}</div>
                                    <div className="col-lg-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8">
                                        <TextInput
                                            type={fields.type}
                                            className="form-control"
                                            name={fields.name}
                                            autoComplete="off"
                                            required
                                            {...(form.formType == 'add' && fields.name == 'brand_code' ? {minLength : "4"} : {})}
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            );
                        })}
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-danger">
                            Save
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-warning" onClick={() => resetForm()}>
                            Reset Form
                        </button>
                    </ValidationForm>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default TestForm;
```

The code above works fine when the props received from the parent component doesn't change, and when I try to reset the form via *onClick* trigger button, it works fine too. But when I want to reset the form when the props of the parent component changes, it generates an error like this:

*Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state*

Can anyone help me solve this problem? I am very grateful beforehand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try moving `useCompare` check to a side effect:

```
useEffect( () => {
    if ( !useCompare(form) ) {
        resetForm()
    }
}, [useCompare, form, resetForm] )
```

You will likely have to wrap `resetForm` in a `useCallback` hook.

This `useEffect` will run every time `form` changes, and placing it here should prevent the 'update during render' issue.

Comment: @Nick ..did not get it properly. Please explain it more why need to use useEffect() here

Comment: Initially, within the render method, he was trying to reset a form that is being passed in as a prop.  This would modify the prop before the render completes.  The proper way would be to allow the render to complete, then reset the form if necessary (in a useEffect hook.)